# Compilation in codeblocks

Tags: c++, windows, output, codeblocks

I need help
I use codeblocks to coding C++ programs. 
It compile C programs well. But I can't compile **C++** programs in my codeblocks.
When try to compile, it shows,

> cannot open output file G:\My Programmes\snack game.exe Permission
>   denied  === Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===

Now what I need to do ? please somone help.

[I've cheked my compiler and debugger and it is both gcc and g++]
I know this type of problem occur in windows but I never face before.

Comment: This is not a codeblocks issue - if you compile the code from the command line you will get the same problems.

Comment: This problem may cause due to anti-virus that you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the target file failed. I can think of several reasons why that could happen:

1. The program is running.
2. The file diesn't have write permission.
3. The directory where the file should be written doesn't exist.
4. The directory diesn't have write permission.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing....

a previous version of the program is still running (even if you don't see any window). This keeps the `.exe` file locked so it cannot be overwritten by the compiler with the new version.

Double check with task manager if there are any `snack game.exe` processes running and kill them.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen, if your program does not close cleanly, and keeps on running in the background. You can use the **process manager** to see if there are any instances of your executable still alive and kill them. 
[Task Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323527)